# How to split "sTest_Val_1 < 50" string to "sTest_Val_1", "<", "50"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a True or False value by putting a value in the sTest_Val_1 ("30") variable.

So we try to split and separate variables and operators.

At first I used the following source code.

However, this source code has caused problems because it is also splitting "_" from sTest_Val_1.

I could not split properly because of special characters in variables. So I could not put a value of "30" into the variable.

```
 var expression = "sTest_Val_1 < 50";  //or "sTest_Val_1<50"
 var copy = expression; //"sTest_Val_1 < 50"

 expression = expression.replace(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/g, "#");  //"#_#_# < #"
 var numbers = copy.split(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]+/); //[sTest,Val,1,50]
 var operators = expression.split("#").filter(function (n) { return n }); //[_,_, < ]
 var result = [];
 var sRst = "";

 result.push(numbers[i]);
 sRst += numbers[i];
 if (i < operators.length) {
    result.push(operators[i]);
    sRst += operators[i];

 console.log(sRst);  
 return eval(sRst);  // I want True, False
```

The value of sTest_Val_1 is defined in another page. (i get this value to javascript object  when first page loaded.)

```
string sTest_Val_1 = "30";
string sTest_Val_2 = "30";
string sTimeVal_1 = "65380";
// ....
```

"sTest_Val_1" This value can only contain alphabetic characters in the first character.

However, the length of the characters is random, and the special characters in the characters are also random.
(<,>, +, -, and = are not included.)

My English is not good enough. Please understand.

Comment: Split by space ?

Comment: But I can not be sure that space will be entered.

Comment: Cant you just split by operator?

Comment: Split by operator, then how do I get operator?

Comment: Before you split you regex the expression to catch the operator.

Comment: @cherryJang see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx to find the position of the operator, without knowing the exact operator. `/<|>|\+|\-|=|&&/` will match <, >, +, = or &&

```
var expression = "sTest_Val_1 < 50";  //or "sTest_Val_1<50"
var regResult = /<|>|\+|\-|=|&&/.exec(expression); //match <, >, +, = or &&
if(!regResult.length){ //regResult is an array containing the operators found
   // handle no operator found
}
var opIdx = regResult.index; //the index of the first found operator
var op = regResult[0];
var variable = expression.substring(0, opIdx).trim(); //split until operator and trim whitespaces
var value = expression.substring(opIdx + op.length, expression.length).trim(); //split after operator and trim whitespaces
```

Note: if you are expecting multiple operators in the expression, you should probably loop through regResult and do some modifications to the substring arguments.

Also, using `eval` [is a bad ideea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), I would recommend you to do a switch on the operator and check the condition properly for returning the result of the operation.

Comment: Thanks! Also, thanks for letting me know that eval is a bad idea. You mean use switch ?

Comment: @cherryJang I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to evaluate, but if you can resort to using switch and/or ifs, you should.

Comment: oh! also "sTest_Val_1<50 && sTest_Val_2<50" this can possible?

Comment: Of course, just add it all operators to the regEx with `|` between them ( `/<|>|\+|\-|=|&&/`). But you'll have to take into account the length of the operator when doing the substrings (updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can split by operator (with keeping the operator) with capturing group.

```
expression = "sTest_Val_1 < 50"
expression.split(/(<|>|\+|\-|=|&&)/)
```

will result in `["sTest_Val_1 ", "<", " 50"]`

Comment: Oh Thanks for your answer! This also helpful.